# How strong is Sierpiński theorem about continua?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, continuum-theory

I've just learned about a theorem by Sierpiński, that a continuum can't be partitioned into countably many non-empty closed sets.

Can we partition some continuum into $\aleph_1$ non-empty closed sets without assuming things like the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: The short answer: yes under CH (trivially), sometimes yes under non-CH. See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually quite a deep question. See [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/285780/2060) plus its comments and answers.

In short: it's complicated. I do see some consistency options there in the absence of CH (or MA). Read up on Cichon's diagram and cardinal invariants of the continuum (i.e. a lot of books/papers..) when looking through this thread.

In [this paper by Miller](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Emiller/res/cov.pdf) it's shown that consistenly we can have non-CH and $2^\omega$ partitioned into $\aleph_1$ many closed subsets (thm 4 and 5). Now apply theorem 3. of that paper to get such a partition of $[0,1]$, say.

I hope this helps.