# Dugundji: cofinite topology on countable infinite set is totally path-disconnected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, path-connected

In James Dugundji's *Topology* (1966), chapter V, are the following problems:

> 1.3 Let $X$ be a[n infinite] countable set, with topology $\cal T = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{ A \space \vert \space {\complement}A$ is finite$\}$. Show that $X$ is connected.

> 5.3 Let $X$ be the connected set in 1, Problem 3. Show that $X$ is totally pathwise disconnected. (By definition, $X$ is called totally pathwise disconnected if the only continuous maps $f: I \to X$ are the constant maps.)

The first one is easy: in the cofinite topology, any two nonempty open sets meet, so there's no disconnection of $X$.

The second one was a challenge for me. A path in $X$ must be compact and connected, but all subsets of $X$ are compact and connected, so that doesn't help. Eventually I realized that a map $f: A \to X$ is continuous precisely when all fibers $f^{-1}(x)$ are closed. That led me to [Proving a Sierpiński result on partitions of the unit interval into closed sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775625/proving-a-sierpi%C5%84ski-result-on-partitions-of-the-unit-interval-into-closed-sets/4776769?noredirect=1#comment10176817_4776769).

So that's an answer, but it's hard for me to imagine many beginning topology students getting it. At this point in the text, we haven't even seen compactness, or identification maps, or separation axioms. Here's someone on Math Overflow who also found it not trivial: [Why are the integers with the cofinite topology not path-connected?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970/why-are-the-integers-with-the-cofinite-topology-not-path-connected).

Possibly there's a mistake in the text that makes this problem unusually hard? Certainly it has many small mistakes (you can see where I had to apply a correction above to Problem 1.3).

**Question.** Is there any simpler approach to Problem V.5.3?

I got interested in this question because of a resemblance to the [pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc), which is another space with a homogeneous feel that's connected but totally path-disconnected. The pseudo-arc is Hausdorff, though, which makes it pretty different. So, a **bonus question**: are there other interesting examples of such spaces?

Comment: For many more examples, do a search in pi-base: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=connected%2BTotally%20Path%20Disconnected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is a simpler way to prove this exercise, and the reason is that the conclusion of this exercise implies (and is hence equivalent to) Sierpiński's result.

In other words, if, contrary to Sierpiński, we have a nontrivial decomposition of $[0,1]$ into disjoint closed sets $\{A_i\}$ then we may define $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb N$ by $f(x)=i$ for $x\in A_i$.  Then the inverse image of every finite set is closed, hence $f$ is a continuous and nonconstant map, contradicting the conclusion of the exercise.

Therefore a simple proof for the exercise would give a simple proof for Sierpiński's theorem itself.

Answer (score 0):

The proof you describe is essentially what's used by Steen and Seebach in *Counterexamples* (though something about non-emptyness should have been clarified):

[image: scan of Counterexamples]

I agree that's flexing somewhat heavy muscle. But let's consider the fact that the co-finite topology on a set of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ [*is* path-connected](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000016/properties/P000038). So any proof necessarily relies on the cardinality at play here.

Comment: I'm confused: you say something is missing in your proof about $f: K \to X$, but what?

Comment: Yes, the Baire category theorem is substantially later in the book, so probably Dugundji did not have that in mind for solving this problem.

Comment: @PatrickR pointed out off-list that I screwed up the negation of my quantifiers. Given this extra info on the original context, I'm going to delete this answer unless I have a clever fix in the next few days.

Comment: Actually I'll just leave the commentary about cardinality up top but delete the erroneous proof (if anyone cares it's in the edit history).